# Which javascript function would return the number of values under a threshold in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, threshold

I have a processAverage function that returns a value Z by averaging two values sent from a connected device. If this value Z is lower than a threshold (this.limitZ) it triggers an alert on a server.

However, the alert is sent too quickly in my opinion and I would like to slow it down with a function that sends the alert only if the value returned is lower than the threshold limitZ 5 times in the last 10 equations of processAverage.

This is what I came up with so far. First I keep the last 10 results of processAverage in a sliding array:

```
const delimiter = '\n'
const eValues = []
const elmt = []

this.limitZ = 45
const z = this.processAverage(e1, e3)
const i = 0;
do
{i += 1
elmt.push (z)
}
while (i < 10)
```

Now, I have to write a function that returns all the values in the array that are lower than the threshold this.limitZ.

for exemple

```
var filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
  return item < this.limitZ;
});
console.log(filtered);

count(filtered) {
  const =filtered;
  return 
}
```

And then I need a function that would emit the alert when the length of this function filtered is above 5 items. It would probably look like:

```
 if (filtered.length > 5) {
          this.emit('alert', msg)
```

However, I'm not sure how to properly write it and have these functions work together as I don't know JS and everything I try to run tells me there are issues with the variables but I'm also sure there is a simpler way to trigger the alert once 5 values in the array are under the threshold, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you declared const i = 0. Change it to let i = 0. If you declare it with const, you can't reassign it. See documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "sliding array" is not quite implemented correctly, as it will just stop pushing to the array once it has 10 copies of the first z value inside it.

Here's a correct implementation. I've replaced your Z with just a random integer for demonstration purposes, and the for loop is only to show it populating and keeping only the last 10 numbers. In reality, you wouldn't use a loop and would instead push to the array every time you get a new Z value. (This could be done using an interval firing every N milliseconds, for example).

```js
function randomNumber(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);}

var arr = [];
let capacity = 10;
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  let z = randomNumber();
  if(arr.length == capacity)
    arr.splice(0, 1);
  arr.push(z);
}

console.log(arr);
```

The second part is to get the number of elements in arr that are less than the threshold. I'll use 5 as the threshold for this. Don't let the lambda function scare you. It's basically the same thing as `function(e){return e < threshold}`

```
let threshold = 5;
let filtered = arr.filter(e => e <= threshold);
//filtered.length contains the number of elements below the threshold
```

```js
function randomNumber(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);}

var arr = [];
let capacity = 10;
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  let z = randomNumber();
  if(arr.length == capacity)
    arr.splice(0, 1);
  arr.push(z);
}

console.log(arr);

let threshold = 5;
let filtered = arr.filter(e => e <= threshold);

console.log(filtered);
console.log(filtered.length);
```

Then finally you could use `filtered.length` to emit when the number of values is greater than 5. You can run this snippet a few times until you see it both emit when the value is greater than 5 and not emit when the value is 5 or less.

```
if(filtered.length > 5)
    this.emit(...);
```

```js
function randomNumber(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);}

var arr = [];
let capacity = 10;
for(let i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  let z = randomNumber();
  if(arr.length == capacity)
    arr.splice(0, 1);
  arr.push(z);
}

console.log(arr);

let threshold = 5;
let filtered = arr.filter(e => e <= threshold);

console.log(filtered);
console.log(filtered.length);

if(filtered.length > 5)
  console.log("EMIT");
```